# What is the scope of a .NET class attribute change?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, soap, wsdl

I am attempting to use a third-party SOAP API from .NET. As usual, I generated a C# proxy class to call it and everything works fine.

Then I spoke with the vendor and found out that in order to switch between tenants (databases) I must specify a different XML namespace. Problem is, the namespace is baked into the proxy code. Anonymized version:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(
    Name="eStrangeAPI", Namespace="urn:wsTenantSpecific")]
public partial class eTimeWSService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", 
        RequestNamespace="urn:wsTenantSpecific:eStrange",
        ResponseNamespace="urn:wsClientSpecificNamespace:eStrange", ...]
    ...
    public string methodCall(ref Param param) {
        ...
    }
```

So I need to change the `wsTenantSpecific` namespace depending on which account is currently in use. I can grab the attributes on the class and modify them on the fly ...

```
var attr = ((WebServiceBindingAttribute[])
    typeof( eTimeWSService ).GetCustomAttributes(
    typeof( WebServiceBindingAttribute ), false ))[ 0 ];
attr.Namespace = "urn:wsADifferentNameSpace";
```

... but I'm concerned about how threadsafe this is. We could have multiple accounts connected at the same time, running ASP.NET requests on different threads in the same process.

Bottom line question: If I change an attribute, is it changed for the entire process or just the current thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bottom line question: If I change an attribute, is it changed for the entire process or just the current thread?

Neither. And both. It depends.

Attribute objects don't actually exist until someone asks for them, and even then there is no guarantee you will get back the same instance every time you ask - so changing the values on an attribute might well have *no impact whatsoever* on another caller checking the attribute. However, in some scenarios the attribute instance might be cached, in which case you *might* get the same instance, and so it might matter. But! When talking about serializers and similar tools, there's a good bet that meta-programming and cached strategies are being used, so it isn't actually inspecting the attributes each time - indeed, it could well have emitted some dynamic code the first time it needed to, and now has no intention whatsoever of revisiting the reflection aspect.

I would be looking for another approach, personally. Mutating attributes is not a good way to try to do this.

As an example, this writes `hello` / `hello` (the change is lost):

```
using System;
class FooAttribute : Attribute {
    public FooAttribute(string bar) {
        Bar = bar;
    }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
[Foo("hello")]
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        WriteFooBar<Program>();
        var d = (FooAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
            typeof(Program), typeof(FooAttribute));
        d.Bar = "world";
        WriteFooBar<Program>();
    }
    static void WriteFooBar<T>() {
        var bar = ((FooAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
            typeof(T), typeof(FooAttribute))).Bar;
        Console.WriteLine(bar);
    }
}
```

and this similar code writes `hello` / `world` (the change is preserved):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
class FooAttribute : Attribute {
    public FooAttribute(string bar) {
        Bar = bar;
    }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
[Foo("hello")]
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        WriteFooBar<Program>();
        var d = (FooAttribute)TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(typeof(Program))[
            typeof(FooAttribute)];
        d.Bar = "world";
        WriteFooBar<Program>();
    }
    static void WriteFooBar<T>() {
        var bar = ((FooAttribute)TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(typeof(Program))[
            typeof(FooAttribute)]).Bar;
        Console.WriteLine(bar);
    }
}
```

(because `TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes` caches the actual attribute instances per-type, where-as `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` creates new instances per-call)

Comment: Thanks Marc. I had assumed I'd need to try a different approach, but was hoping there was a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way over here is not to use proxy class but send the SOAP request to server which gives total control over xml you want to send and receive to and from server respectively.

Use a HttpWebRequest and WebResponse class to take the control of the soap request. Change the namespace (xmlns:xsi) as per your logic..

For e,g,:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
      Your Request goes here....
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please see [proxy less web service client](http://measuredtwice.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/proxy-less-c-web-service-client.html)

Comment: I thought about that ... this API is super-ugly though :-)